# Uninitialized Constant in Rails 3.0.1 using the RedCloth 4.2.2 gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, initialization, redcloth

I'm having an issue with using RedCloth in my local application. I keep getting the following error:

```
uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::RedCloth
```

This happens because I have the following code:

```
<%= RedCloth.new("Some text").to_html %>
```

What I tried to do is put this in the environment.rb file:

```
require "RedCloth"
```

However, when I do this, I get a huge error with my Phusion Passenger + Nginx configuration, which I've detailed in the following forum: http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=42560

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your Gemfile has a `gem 'RedCloth'` in it. Regardless of which gems are actually installed in your system, Rails will only use the gems listed in your Gemfile. You do not need the `require "RedCloth"` statement either.

Comment: wow...I can't believe that was my problem. Thanks for your help, hopefully no one else runs into this...now i feel like newb.

Comment: +1 I ran into the same problem today. It's partially that I am a newb, and partially that there is nothing in the instructions that tell us to include that in the gemfile. :-/

Comment: @jyoseph: Generally, you **always** need to have any gems you use listed in your `Gemfile` -- it's not just a RedCloth thing.

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same error and gem 'RedCloth' line was present in Gemfile. What helped was adding require statement in the beginning of controller file

```
require 'redcloth'

class StaticController < ApplicationController
...
```

Comment: This worked for me (though I required 'RedCloth' rather than 'redcloth').